# Is there anyway to convert row values to column keys by hive(HQL)?

Tags: sql, database, hive

I have one big database, and some values are formatted in complex type. Eg, 'sat' column keys are formatted as follows:

```
id       sat
5  'a:100, b:200'
6  'b:300, c:150'
7  'some_other_unknown_key:900'
```

I want to convert the table like the following format and do some extra statistics.

```
id        a       b        c  some_other_unknown_key
5        100    200    null   null
6        null    300    150   null
7        null    null   null  900
```

Is there any way to do it without creating new tables by HQL?

Comment: According to the code of conduct, never include a "Thanks" at the end of a question.

Comment: Which DBMS you are using? Oracle, MySQL, SQL Server?

Comment: I am not sure about DBMS. Other guys set it up and provide a web frontend where I can run HQL query. They call it HIVE.

Answer (score 1):

use `REGXP_EXTRACT`

```
select id, regexp_extract(foo,'a:([0-9]+)',1) as a,
           regexp_extract(foo,'b:([0-9]+)',1) as b,
           regexp_extract(foo,'c:([0-9]+)',1) as c from t;
```

Comment: Thanks. It can solve most of my problem. What if 'a', 'b', 'c' is a random value and I don't know what it really is before query?

Comment: @oliver : What you're looking for is dynamic Pivot . There's no straight way to do that. You have to use another procedural language / script ( Java / Shell script ) to construct the query dynamically like the above one before running it. A better approach is to change your table design and store values separately or using a json, as the column sat looks close to being a json.

Answer (score 1):

Also you can try to convert your string to valid JSON (add double-quotes and curly braces), then use json_tuple to  extract columns, but anyway you should know column names and list them in the query, hive cannot select columns dynamically.

Demo:

```
with your_table as (--Use your table instead of this
select stack(3, 5, 'a:100, b:200',
                6, 'b:300, c:150',
                7, 'some_other_unknown_key:900'
             ) as (id, sat) 
)

 select t.id, p.a, p.b, p.c, p.some_other_unknown_key
   from your_table t
        lateral view outer json_tuple(concat('{',regexp_replace(t.sat,'([a-z_A-Z]*):','\\"$1\\":'),'}'), 'a','b','c','some_other_unknown_key') p as a,b,c,some_other_unknown_key;
```

Result:

```
OK
id      a       b       c       some_other_unknown_key
5       100     200     NULL    NULL
6       NULL    300     150     NULL
7       NULL    NULL    NULL    900
Time taken: 0.128 seconds, Fetched: 3 row(s)
```

If the data contains some keys not listed in the query, they will be not extracted.